# How can I replace the summing in numpy matrix multiplication with concatenation in a new dimension?

Tags: numpy, 3d, concatenation, matrix-multiplication, operation

For each location in the result matrix, instead of storing the dot product of the corresponding row and column in the argument matrices, I would like like to store the element wise product, which will be a vector extending into a third dimension.

One idea would be to convert the argument matrices to vectors with vector entries, and then take their outer product, but I'm not sure how to do this either.

EDIT:

I figured it out before I saw there was a reply. Here is my solution:

```
def newdot(A, B):
  A = A.reshape((1,) + A.shape)
  B = B.reshape((1,) + B.shape)

  A = A.transpose(2, 1, 0)
  B = B.transpose(1, 0, 2)

  return A * B
```

What I am doing is taking apart each row and column pair that will have their outer product taken, and forming two lists of them, which then get their contents matrix multiplied together in parallel.

Answer (score 3):

It's a little convoluted (and difficult to explain) but this function should get you what you're looking for:

```
def f(m1, m2):
    return (m2.A.T * m1.A.reshape(m1.shape[0],1,m1.shape[1]))

m3 = m1 * m2
m3_el = f(m1, m2)

m3[i,j] == sum(m3_el[i,j,:])
m3 == m3_el.sum(2)
```

The basic idea is to turn the matrices into arrays and do element-by-element multiplication. One of the arrays gets reshaped to have a size of one in its middle dimension, and array broadcasting rules expand this dimension out to match the height of the other array.

Comment: You can replace you reshape with `m1.A[:, None, :]`, which makes it more compact and (I think) more readable.